Django post request is good in postman but not from frontend with the same payload
Django API interface and Postman is working fine in posting the payload, however with the exact same payload posted from my frontend it doesn't work even while disabling cors.
-This is my mode:
class Activity(models.Model):     
    cid = models.CharField(max_length=10)     
    percent = models.IntegerField()     
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

-this is my view:
class ActivityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Activity.objects.all()
serializer_class = ActivitySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset  # Start with the base queryset
    
        # Get the cid from the query parameters
        cid = self.request.query_params.get('cid')
    
        # If cid is provided in the query parameters, filter the queryset
        if cid:
            queryset = queryset.filter(cid=cid)
    
        return queryset

-this is my url:
router.register(r'activities', ActivityViewSet)

And this is my frontend code:
const postOutcomesAsync = async () =\> {
function getCSRFToken() {
const csrfCookie = document.cookie.match(/csrftoken=(\[\\w-\]+)/);
if (csrfCookie) {
return csrfCookie\[1\];
}
return null;
}
const csrfToken = getCSRFToken();

              axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/activities/', inputValues[2], {
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
                }
              });
        
            console.log('All activities posted successfully');
            
          } 

The backend log shows OPTIONS 200 ok and no posting at all. Network tab shows post request failed but OPTIONS 200 ok. Axios shows network error 500.

Network error 500 is Django’s internal server error. Ensure DEBUG=True then share the error you get.

Can CORS be an issue?

When I removed the csrtf token from the request it worked, it's so weird that it happened accross all of my Django applications in different folders??. Before, token was needed now it's not. And I don't remember doing anything xd
